# What does the "char **envp;" of FCGX_Request mean in FastCGI?

Tags: c, fastcgi

In FastCGI, there is a pointer, envp, of struct FCGX_Request. Here is the code :

```
typedef struct FCGX_Request {
    int requestId;            /* valid if isBeginProcessed */
    int role;
    FCGX_Stream *in;
    FCGX_Stream *out;
    FCGX_Stream *err;
    char **envp;

    /* Don't use anything below here */

    struct Params *paramsPtr;
    int ipcFd;               /* < 0 means no connection */
    int isBeginProcessed;     /* FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST seen */
    int keepConnection;       /* don't close ipcFd at end of request */
    int appStatus;
    int nWriters;             /* number of open writers (0..2) */
    int flags;
    int listen_sock;
} FCGX_Request;
```

I guess it means the environment variable of somewhere. Is the browser's or the webserver's environment variable?

Maybe I know little about the WEB, but I guess this should be something about the transmission between the browser and the webserver. So the *envp* is sent by the broswer to the webserver? If that's true, can anybody show me some details about the *envrioment variable*?

What's more, with FCGX_Request::in I can get some *POST* or *GET* actions, which is submitted by the browser. And I can put the result into FCGX_Request::out to sent to the browser.
My question is, is there any other things I can learn?

Any link of keyword is welcome. thanks~

Comment: For learning, I would recommend starting with CGI. Or really, start with HTTP. FastCGI is an optimisation of CGI and it really requires knowledge of CGI to understand. But if you want a link, have you read http://fastcgi.com?

Comment: I won't put my hand into fire for it, but it's probably the environment where the (fast)cgi program runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess it means the environment variable of somewhere. Is the
> browser's or the webserver's environment variable?

It's a pointer to an array of string pointers containing the environment variables passed by client (webserver) to the server (application), it's used internally by `FCGX_GetParam()`. You can use it if you want to iterate through all variables but you should not mutate it or retain any pointers past the end of request.

> ... I guess this should be something about the transmission between the
> browser and the webserver. So the envp is sent by the broswer to the
> webserver? If that's true, can anybody show me some details about the
> envrioment variable?

The browser uses the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) to talk with the webserver. The webserver uses [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) protocol and [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) to interface your application.

The envp contains specific CGI and HTTP variables as defined by the standard, [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1).

> My question is, is there any other things I can learn?

Knowledge about mentioned protocols would probably be good start. The FastCGI dev kit's [documentation](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/overview.html) and [examples](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/). [`fcgiapp.h`](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/include/fcgiapp.h) contains documentation for most public functions.